# MySQL - Return Row Where Current Date Between Start and End Date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, time

I have searched everywhere and can't find an answer for this.

The table below shows the class start and end time.

I am looking to return the row where the current time falls in-between the current start and end time.

The start and End time are going to be variable dependent on current time, so can't input specific values.

[image: MySQL Table showing Class ID, start and end time]

An exmaple being, Say if the current time is:

**2016-02-05 20:15:00**

Then it would return the row where **Class ID is 6**.

Comment: Is there something you don't understand about `now()` and `between` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE Class_Start_Timestamp > GETDATE()
AND Class_End_Timestamp < GETDATE()
```

If the columns are not datetime:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE CAST(Class_Start_Timestamp AS datetime) > GETDATE()
AND CAST(Class_End_Timestamp AS datetime) < GETDATE()
```

You can also use "NOW()" (mysql) and "BETWEEN", but a quick google should have yielded many options...

Comment: I used the Now and Between. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use any of the below queries

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN Class_Start_Timestamp AND Class_End_Timestamp
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE NOW() >= Class_Start_Timestamp AND NOW() <= Class_End_Timestamp
```